# Getting image sizes like Facebook link scraper

Tags: python, facebook, image-processing

I'm implementing my own link scraper to copy Facebook's technique as closely as possible (unless someone has a ready made lib for me...).

According to the many answers on SO, Facebook's process for determining the image to associate with a shared link involves searching for several recognized meta tags and then, if those are not found, stepping through the images on the page and returning a list of appropriately sized ones (at least 50px by 50px, have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1, and in PNG, JPEG or GIF format according to [this answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/7623986/165673))

My question is, how does Facebook get the size information of the images? Is it loading all images for each shared link and inspecting them? Is there more efficient way to do this. (My backend is Python.)

(Side note: Would it make sense to use a client-side instead of server-side approach?)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there more efficient way to do this.

Most common “web” graphic formats – JPEG, GIF, PNG – contain info about the width & height in the header (or at least in the first block, for PNG).

So if the remote web server is accepting *range requests* it’d be possible to only request the first *X* bytes of an image resource instead of the whole thing to get the desired information.

(This is what Facebook’s scraper does for HTML pages, too – it’s quite common that you see in the debugger that the request was answered with HTTP status code *206 Partial Content* – that meaning Facebook said they’re only interested in the first *X* (K)Bytes (for meta elements in head), and the web server was able to give them only that.